# Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient post send special characters (A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client)

Tags: c#, uwp, asp.net-mvc-2, httpclient

I need to send the following text to a web application (MVC2)

> Hello <>~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><
>
> Hello <>?:"P{{}|+)_)_&*()&^*^%&#%^@#$~!@#~!@#~Q

I'm sending this by a UWP app using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient. However, when this message received from the web it throws an exception.

> "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (data="..._&*()&^*^%&#%^@#$~!@#~!@#~Q")."

The same message can be sent by Android and iOS apps and web server accepts it with no issue. Can someone help me to solve this without any server-side modification?

Here is the code I used on UWP app. Please let me know if need any alteration in here. Thanks again.

```
var httpBaseProtocolFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
    httpBaseProtocolFilter.MaxVersion = HttpVersion.Http20;
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpBaseProtocolFilter);
    var requestUrl = Global.ServerUrl;

    httpClient = SetHeaders(httpClient);

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new HttpMediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;

    if (requestMehtod == ApplicationConstants.RequestType.POST) //Request type POST
    {
        if (postData != null && postData.Count > 0)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var item in postData)
            {
                val = (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Value)) ? "" : item.Value;
                pairs.Add(item.Key, val);
            }

            Uri uri = new Uri(requestUrl);
            HttpFormUrlEncodedContent formContent = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
            response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, formContent).AsTask(cts.Token);
        }
    }

    responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Have you verified, that your key-value pairs are properly URL encoded? They appear to contain reserved characters, that need to be escaped. Either take a look at the URL in your debugger, or use a network traffic analyzer tool to see, what URL is sent over the wire.

Comment: I also noticed that above sting throws an exception but below one does not. ~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|::"<>?,./;'[]\=-/
/,.';\][',..=--54_(*^(%+_@%+_%$+_()!@~%^*(#!_!_!_$#*/-/-*-*/-
./'];][{}{{\\\//

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes I think encoding works. I get the following output for my string. data=Hello+%3C%3E~%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26%2A%28%29_%2B%7C%7D%7B%22%3A%3F%3E%3C%0D%0AHello+%3C%3E%3F%3A%22P%7B%7B%7D%7C%2B%29_%29_%26%2A%28%29%26%5E%2A%5E%25%26%23%25%5E%40%23%24~%21%40%23~%21%40%23~Q%27

Comment: `Hello+%3C%3E` decodes into `Hello+<>`, but you claim to be sending `Hello <>`. Is this a typo, or is something going on that we aren't aware of?

Comment: I think space character replaced into a +

Comment: Ah, true. In this case the [modified form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application/x-www-form-urlencoded_type) is used (`+` instead of `%20`).

Comment: I found the issue. "&" character is not acceptable on the MVC2 web. However "^&" is accepting. I think "^" is escaping the & character. That's why one string is ok and the other one is not.

Comment: That does not explain, why *the same URL* is accepted by the same server when sent from Android or iOS, and rejected when sent from a Windows application.

Comment: Oh! I forgot that part. Our ignorant developers on Android and iOS team replaces the & character with 'and'. Kept their mouth shut the whole time. I was thinking of replacing the "&" with a special character like char(128) and ask the backend developers to replace it back with a "&". Is this a good solution? (Sorry for wasting your time :) )

Comment: URL form encoded URL's use a standard encoding. There doesn't seem to be any immediately obvious reason to deviate from it. Have your backend developers fix their server code, and get your Android/iOS developers to adhere to an established standard. As for `char(128)`: That's surely going to break in spectacular ways, when interpreted as UTF-8 (which is almost a given).